# Filter rows of a DataFrame based on the value of an attribute of a column value

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas.DataFrame contains a column that contains timestamp values.

I specifically want to work with those rows that lie within a specific time-of-day range, from start hour to end hour, ignoring the date part.

I tried to implement this using a boolean array as an index:

```
import datetime
import pandas
from random import randrange as rr

# generate random timestamps
timestamps = [datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,rr(24),rr(60)) for i in xrange(100)]
# insert into DataFrame
df = pandas.DataFrame(timestamps, columns=["t"])
# try to filter based on time range
morning = df[8 <= df.t.hour < 12]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    morning = df[8 <= df.t.hour < 12]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1815, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

I've tried to work around this:

```
morning = df[8 <= df.t.apply(lambda x:x.hour) < 12]
```

But this also fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    morning = df[8 <= df.t.apply(lambda x:x.hour) < 12]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 676, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone suggest a method how to filter rows of a DataFrame based on the value of an attribute of a column value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the following:

```
df[(df['t'].dt.hour >= 8) & (df['t'].dt.hour < 12)]
```

Firstly as the dtype are `datetime64` then you have the [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessors to return just the `hour` component you can use this to perform a comparison.

As you're looking for a range then you need to use 2 conditions `and` using the `&` operator as we're dealing with arrays and wrap the conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence

```
In [236]:
morning = df[(df['t'].dt.hour >= 8) & (df['t'].dt.hour < 12)]
morning

Out[236]:
                     t
8  2000-01-01 09:09:00
18 2000-01-01 10:30:00
20 2000-01-01 11:58:00
21 2000-01-01 10:11:00
22 2000-01-01 10:39:00
32 2000-01-01 08:51:00
35 2000-01-01 10:32:00
42 2000-01-01 10:57:00
46 2000-01-01 11:45:00
55 2000-01-01 08:58:00
56 2000-01-01 10:26:00
60 2000-01-01 10:33:00
66 2000-01-01 11:13:00
70 2000-01-01 10:29:00
79 2000-01-01 08:23:00
80 2000-01-01 08:08:00
83 2000-01-01 10:44:00
86 2000-01-01 11:02:00
93 2000-01-01 11:14:00
97 2000-01-01 08:55:00
98 2000-01-01 10:47:00
```

Comment: So now it complains that the `'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'`. I'm using version '0.13.1' - is this feature available in later versions?

Comment: yes you'll need to upgrade to at least [`0.15.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#dt-accessor)